# Spring Integration - 2 MessageHandlers handle half of messages

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-jdbc

I am using spring integration framework, with a Transformer

inputChannel -> kafka consumer
outputChannel -> database jdbc writer

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel inboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

   @Bean
    public DirectChannel outboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel="inboundChannel", outputChannel="outboundChannel")
public JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToObjectTransformer() {
    return new JsonToObjectTransformer(Item.class);
}




@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannel")
public MessageHandler jdbcmessageHandler() {
    JdbcMessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler = new ...

    return ...;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundChannel")
public MessageHandler kafkahandler() {
    return new ...;
}
```

in  both handlers I override

```
public void handleMessage(Message<?> message)
```

The problem: if in kafka there are total N messages,
then each handleMessage() is invoked exactly n/2 times!

I assumed that each handler will be invoked n times, because each handler linked to different channel and there are n messages in total.

What am I missing?

(if I disable the kafak handler, the second handler gets all n messages)

Update:
I need to subscriber to get all the messages from the same channel (kafka handler will do something with the raw data, and jdbc handler will push the transformed
data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your `inboundChannel` and `outboundChannel` are out of use: you nowhere (at least in the question) specify their names.

The names like `input` and `output` are taken by the framework and used to create new `MessageChannel` beans, which are used in other places.

Now see what you have:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel="input"
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
```

Both of them are subscribers to the same `input` channel and since it is created automatically by the framework as a `DirectChannel`. This channel is based on a round-robin `LoadBalancingStrategy`, therefore you see `n/2` in your Kafka since its service activator deals only with every second message sent to that `input` channel.

Please, see more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/core.html#channel-configuration-directchannel

Comment: Ok, first sorry for the confusion, the names are bit different, I changed them for simplicity, didn't realize they used by the system. should be outboundChannel inboundChannel. I fixed the question. now, can I subscribe to same channel from 2 sources and "release" the messages?

Comment: Of course, you can, but it is still a `DirectChannel` with a default round-robin balancing strategy. If you want to distribute the same message to several subscribers, consider to use a `PiblishSubscribeChannel` instead.